# Carrier Furnace Blower Motor Won't Run

Tags: furnace, blower, motor, carrier

Troubleshooting 25-yr old Carrier Furnace. Blower motor will not start. 24V at terminal strip (R and COM) on board. Checked all (4) limit switches; cleaned flame sensor and replaced igniter. Finally replaced blower motor. No change. Relay on control board clicks but fan motor will not run.

Comment: Are you getting voltage at the motor?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.